# How to make desktop shortcuts on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: gnome, 16.04, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

I was wondering how to do that, this is not something vital for me but I find it useful to know. I found some ways to do this for older versions and I don't know if they can be applied to 16.04. I also tried using Gnome Panel but i just couldn't find a path to a specific app.

[image: Gnome panel]

Comment: Apps are in `/usr/share/applications`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I got it, help appreciated. I commented on an answer below explaining how I did it, I also tried your way and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Gnome Panel dialog box you have there, you need to enter the name of the application and **the command that would be used to launch it from a terminal**. For example, to add a launcher for GIMP:

**Name**: GIMP
**Command**: `gimp`

since, to launch Gimp, you can just type `gimp`. The same is true for many applications. The comment is optional - text you enter would come up when you hover the cursor over the icon

**Comment**: the awesomest image editor

Of course, you need to figure out what command launches your application.

Here's an example. On my system I have a program in `/opt/lks-indicator` that has to be run with Python. So to make a launcher for it using that dialog I would enter:

**Name**: Lock-Keys Indicator
**Command**: python /opt/lks-indicator/lks-indicator.py
**Comment**: shows in panel whether lock keys are on

[image]

You can click the icon image and browse for an appropriate image for your application if it doesn't automatically get set to the right one.

Save the file created in `~/.local/share/applications` and then drag and drop the file to the launcher panel.

The more complicated but more customisable way to make a new launcher, by creating your own `.desktop` file for the application, also works in 16.04, and is explained beautifully [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/68023/527764).

Comment: It worked and I'm thankful though I just used a name under the app I wanted when you search for it in "Alt+F2" search bar for example I used a game named Colobot(I also tried with Chromium browser and it worked too) which I downloaded from the store and simply entered that name in the command field. The icon changed automatically and that's it.

Comment: Yep, the name od the application is usually the command to launch it :)

Comment: I see my lks-indicator became useful in more than one way lol